# 'module' object has no attribute 'NORM_L1'

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote the following code to normalize an image using Python and OpenCV. When I tried to compile the following code I get the following error. Could you please help me to solve it ?

```
`import cv2.cv as cv`
` import numpy`
  import normalize

img=cv.LoadImage("img.jpg",0)
mat=cv.GetMat(img)
a = numpy.asarray(mat)   #store the pixels in the input array

dst=[]      # declare the output array

cv.Normalize(a,dst,0,255,cv.NORM_L1)
print a
```